# Deploy oracle 11g and vb.net 2015 application on client machine

Tags: windows, vb.net, oracle, crystal-reports

i have developed an application on windows 10 with oracle 11g enterprise, Vb.net community 2015 using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client and Crystal Reports, now i have to deploy the application on windows 10 client , please guide me how i create installation package and how i configure client machine using Instant Client

Comment: What have you done and where are you stuck?  SO is not a tutorial site I'm afraid.  You need to do your research first and then post a question here if you get stuck with something specific.

Comment: i need  to download Instant Client from oracle site but there are many options, different kind of packages there  , can u tell me which option is suite to my scenario ?

Comment: You don't need to install the Oracle Instant Client, you just need single DLL `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`

Comment: thank you Wernfried Domscheit --- , Please tell me some more about it , do i copy the dll in client machine?? ,wat i should do